# Interpreting predictions of RFs based on AUCs

Tags: r, random-forest, interpretation, auc

If I have a random forest of old independent data with an AUC of .66, a random forest of new independent data with an AUC of .75, and a random forest of old and new independent data with an AUC of .79, what can I inference by the AUC of the old+new independent data, given the AUCs previously mention.

EDIT: These are all validation AUCs. All RFs were trained on and for a binary classification outcome using 4 explanatory continuous variables for the new data, one explanatory continuous variable for the old data.

Comment: I heavily used random forests in R for a while, and I never heard the term `AUC`.  What does it mean?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's the **A**rea **U**nder the **C**urve (the ROC curve), a very common model performance metric for binary classification models. [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Area_under_the_curve)

Comment: In any case, look into use `importance` with the `randomForest` package.  Assessing the strength of your model is not too dependent on the application of random forests, AFAIK.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it belongs on stats.stackexchange not Stack Overflow. As far as I know, *predictive power* doesn't have a mathematical definition, so you might want to clarify what you're looking for. Also, are these validation AUCs or training AUCs? More data should lead to a better model, but maybe you're overfitting more in model 2 and 3...

Comment: How were the AUC calculated? On the training data? Using cross-validation? Is it a binary classification problem? What do you mean by "predictive power of the new data above and beyond that of the old data"?

Comment: @DataD'oh Question modified to clarify.

Comment: @JonathanRauscher I still do not understand what you mean by "above and beyond that of the old data".

Comment: @DataD'oh I've changed the question around to better reflect what I am looking for.

Comment: More data usually makes a model better.

Comment: I'm still confused. Your new + old data improved your AUC from .66 to .79. What more do you want to say than that?

Comment: @Gregor I'm confused why the lift from new data on its own to new+old is a small lift increase. This led me to the idea that multicollinearity might exist, but my diagnostics don't show that. Perhaps the old data just isn't all that great in the presence of the new data?

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear because the post does not ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Having more data usually makes models better. I don't think that there's much more to be said.

Answer (score 0):

> using 4 explanatory continuous variables for the new data, one
>   explanatory continuous variable for the old data

So for the new model you used something like y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, but in the old model it was just y ~ x1?

If this is correct then it's not a surprise that you registered a higher AUC.

Also is x1 in the new model the same as x1 in the old model? I mean the same variable. Because if that's the case you could say that x1 impacts heavily on performance, but x2-x4 improve accuracy too.

You should compare the performance that you have between the old and new model (plus the old+new model), using the same explanatory variables (same number, same variables).

Also the number of observations should be the same for a meaningful comparison between the models.

If observations are randomly picked than you should also repeat *k* times for consistency, ie: repeat the 3 models on *n* observation sampled from your population.

> what can I inference by the AUC of the old+new independent data, given
>   the AUCs previously mention

To me not much, because as I mentioned above the models are different. Try use the same number of variables first.